# React Material UI TextField not working with useForm hook reset method

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am working on a project using React and MUI; in my forms i am using useForm form react-hook-form, something like this

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   const defaultValues = new Provider();
   defaultValues.code = '123';
   defaultValues.name = 'some name';
   reset({...defaultValues});
}, []);
```

And the TextFields are declared like this

```
<TextField
            id="codeInput"
            required
            label="Code"
            variant="outlined"
            error={!!errors['code']}
            helperText={errors['code'] ? errors['code'].message : ''}
            {...register('code')}/>
          <TextField
            id="nameInput"
            required
            label="Name"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{width: '75vw'}}
            error={!!errors['name']}
            helperText={errors['name'] ? errors['name'].message : ''}
            {...register('name')}/>
```

I even tried to assign the value like this

```
setValue('code', '123', {shouldDirty: true, shouldTouch: true});
setValue('name', 'some name', {shouldDirty: true, shouldTouch: true});
```

But the TextFields look like this when displayed

[image: Fields]

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was a problem with the TextField component, the placement and behavior of the label in the TextField is ruled by properties and by handling that properties i could make the component work the way i wanted

Something like this:

```
const [labelProps, setLabelProps] = React.useState<any>({});
setLabelProps({shrink: true});
.....
.....
<TextField
   InputLabelProps={labelProps}/>
```